# Why would an incoming call from one person show up as a different person from my contact name list?

Tags: iphone, contacts

I received a call that showed up as someone from my contact list. When I played the message back it was from a completely different business. This has happened once before... a call came in with the Contra Costa County Sheriff listed as the caller and it was a telemarketer not from the Sheriff's office. Why would this happen? How do I fix it?

The last call this happened to was from a legitimate medical office that was trying to schedule a follow up visit. It showed up as a different person's name that is not associated at all with the doctor's office. I can't imagine that the doctor's office is spoofing.

Comment: Caller ID spoofing, probably.

Comment: You can't fix it because it originates outside your iPhone.  Scammers do this, as @tubedogg indicated, to fool people into answering their phones.

Comment: The last call that this happened to was from my hematologist's office to remind me that I am due for a follow up. I can't imagine that they are spoofing. Is there another reason this could be happening?

Comment: One thing you might want to do tho, is be very careful what apps and websites you allow to access your contacts.   What happens is a telemarketer spoofs the phone number of someone found in your contacts to fool you into answering.

Comment: I have never heard of or seen examples of this type of issue that want caused by either 1) spoofing, or 2) user error. Many medical offices use different numbers to make outgoing calls then the numbers we use to call them. Also, staff could be using a personal or company phone to make calls. Either way, the number wouldn't display as the one in your contact.